# Vuejs, Webpack & dynamic import, whole app

Tags: javascript, webpack, vue.js, import, vuejs2

I am trying to load a whole application dynamically from my client side js code. I do not want to send any of the dependencies needed for loading the app to the browser unless the app is called.

Ideally I would also not need to use the build which includes the compiler.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';

export default function fetchAppFromServer() {

Vue.component('App', () => import(/* webpackChunkName: "ui" */ './App.vue')
        .then((app) => console.log('here I am!', app))
);

    createDivForMount(); // this makes <div id="cmp-app"></div>

    const vm = new Vue(App).$mount('#cmp-app');
    Promise.resolve()
}
```

I would then in another file call:

```
logic1()
  .then(result => logic2)
  .then(fetchAppFromServer())
```

EDIT: From the comment below I am just expanding on what the issue is, which is mainly that the above code does not work :) , I am unable to :

- Load the app when a function is called.
- Create a webpack code split
  point to generate a new file containing just the UI

Comment: And what's the problem ?

Comment: The issue is that I am not able to get that flow to work, I need to import Vue itself, and mount the app to the dom. It is different from just the traditional use case of calling an extra component dynamically. Can you help? @BelminBedak